# How to attach react code to html properly? (I get "Target container is not a DOM element" error)

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to setup a react web app with webpack 4, but I can't make it working, I get "Uncaught Invariant Violation: Target container is not a DOM element." console error.

I spent last 2 days trying everything and I've read all similar problems here in stackoverflow but nothing worked for me.

It should be a stupid bug (a typo or bad config) but I can't see it, for some reason it can't find my html file or div element with 'app' id.

My project structure:

[image: Structure]

This is the generated html by html webpack plugin:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Webpack App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='app'></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My html template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Webpack App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='app'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';

const App = () => {

  return (
    <div>
      {'foobar'}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: `./src/index.html`,
      filename: `index.html`
    })
  ]
};
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not use `create-react-app`? It does all of this for you

Comment: @Hybrid I know, I already did some projects using create-react-app and now for this one I want to make it from scratch to have a better understand but seems I can't pass the first level.

Comment: @Understandable! Unfortunately I don't have an answer to your question, but if I were you, I would start a new create-react-app, and then run `npm run eject` to see all the outputted files. I'm sure there's a ton you could learn from that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
I was importing a component from one of my ui projects in App.js, I removed it an now is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the code you provided with the same file structure (not including the jest and eslint files) you had and it successfully ran. Therefore, it's probably the inconsistencies in your webpack or babel versions that's causing the bug. Maybe you can try looking at my package.json compared to yours. Hope this helps!

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "http-server": "^0.11.1",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.3.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6"
  }
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ]
}
```